# Is it possible to run ajax based php files in localhost/offline

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I can run php application in localhost without ajax/JQuery usage in it.

If i use ajax/JQuery its connecting to google api's which needs to have Internet connection. I prepared the whole Application for offline but its not working properly without internet connection.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

I tried the above code like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajax/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

by downloading the jquery.min.js from the url shown above. but its not working.
So finally,
Is there any possibility to run the ajax based php application offline/localhost.

Please let me know, Thanks in advance...

Comment: make sure your `jQuery` reside inside `ajax` folder at `root`.

Comment: Most likely the path "ajax/jquery.min.js" is a 404 - just check for it. If you want to avoid the dns lookup timeout (the delay when you load the page when offline) you'll need to remove the request for `src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/...` incidentally it's normally written as a protocol-relative url meaning: `src=//ajax.googleapis.com/...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used jQuery from a cdn. You can download the jquery file and store it in your application directory and link it in your file. Then you will have the functionality of jQuery available in your application. It doesn't need to have an internet connection when all the files you are using in your application are located in the directory of your application. When Jquery is available you can use ajax or other functions without any problem.